# Is there a way to check the different versions for a npm library before installing?

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic3

Im looking to explore a fix to a problem with a part of the sqlite library not being accessible inside my Ionic 3 project.  The version I installed is new and Im wondering if it might be a dependency issue which could be fixed with a different version.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there a way to check all the available versions for a library.

```
npm view @ionic-native/sqlite versions  --json
```

For Ionic 3, try installing the version 4.20.0

```
npm i -s @ionic-native/sqlite@4.20.0
```

Reference : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15225#issuecomment-414074074